# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Objective is to take the date from the delta table & if it is yesterday date i.e transaction date not found then in else part yesterday date minus it from the current date and process the another notebook in for loop need to use pyspark.

```
fromdate=spark.sql("select to_date(max(time),'yyyy-mm-dd') date from default.table")
display(x)
print("latest TransactionDate not found")
todate = datetime.date.today()
dates = todate-fromdate
```

> Error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str' at line 5

Please share the effective code for write in the if else way.

[image]

Comment: `fromdate` is a dataframe object not a datetime, to get the date into python variable use  `fromdate = fromdate.first().date`

Comment: hello I used like this 
import datetime
fromdate=spark.sql("select max(time) as latestlog from default.table")
fromdate1 = fromdate.first().date
get error 
AttributeError: date

Comment: Nope I need to take the max date from the sql table I tried both fromdate1 = fromdate.first().lastestlog  (Attribute error) & fromdate1 = fromdate.collect()[0][0] (Exception: Cannot call display(<class 'datetime.date'>))

Comment: This works for me x=fromdate.orderBy("latestlog", ascending=False).head(1)[0][0].

Comment: Is there any better way to put in the if/else block like if it is previous date display transaction date not found else find the days difference and run all the notebook in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import datetime
df=spark.sql("select to_date('2021-12-25','yyyy-MM-dd') date ")
fromdate = df.collect()[0][0]
todate = datetime.date.today()
print(fromdate)
print(todate)
days = (todate - fromdate).days
print(days)
```